# How should I fix this door jamb?

Tags: door-frame

The bottom of my kitchen door has rotted. How do I fix it?

[image: left door jamb] [image: right door jamb]

Comment: How large is the cavity, and is there anything else in there (wires, pipes, etc.)?

Comment: What caused the hole? Is the rest of it solid?

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear what I'm looking at here. I'd have expected a solid board in a door of that age, but it looks hollow somehow.

Comment: What is above? And can you assess the sturdiness of the studs beside the jamb?

Comment: @kaya3 Nothing else in there, just rotten wood.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose the other half poked it. It is solid from about 30cm up.

Comment: @isherwood that's what it is supposed to be, but it has rotted. Mostly dust now.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate good wood is still present above ~30cm. Brick looks ok.

Comment: Given that you’re trying to fasten accurately to brick, it might be easier (though more material intensive) to replace the entire piece of jamb.